# smoothness of harmonic functions confusion in proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

can you explain that last two steps?
how that $$na(n)r^{n-1}$$ disappeared in next integral?I noticed the transformation of variables but still not able to figure out properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in Evans $n\alpha(n)$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in 
$\mathbb{R}^n$, so that 
$$
\int_0^{\varepsilon}{\eta}\Bigl(\frac{r}{\varepsilon}\Bigr)n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}dr=
\int_0^{\varepsilon}\biggl(\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\eta\Bigl(\frac{r}{\varepsilon}\Bigr)\,dS\biggr)\,dr=
\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\eta\Bigl(\frac{r}{\varepsilon}\Bigr)\,dy.
$$